# OpenGL Vertex Array/Buffer Objects

Tags: opengl, vbo, vao

**Question 1**

Do vertex buffer objects created under a certain VAO deleted once that VAO is deleted?

An example:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObject);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(someVertices), someVertices, 
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

When later calling `glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);`, will `bufferObject` be deleted as well?

The reason I'm asking is that I saw a few examples over the web that didn't delete those buffer objects.

**Question 2**

What is the maximum amount of memory that I can allocate for buffer objects? It must be system dependent of course, but I can't seem find an estimation for it. What happens when video RAM isn't big enough? How would I know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Answer 1**

It depends. If you called `glDeleteBuffers` before, it will be deleted when you delete the VAO. If not, it won't. The VAO holds a reference to the VBO, and so does your application after calling `glGenBuffers`. Both references need to be released before the VBO is deleted.

**Answer 2**

There's (afaik) no way to query the maximum amount you can allocate. However, according to the [reference documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml), `glBufferData` will emit `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` if a buffer can not be allocated.

Comment: Do VBOs and VAOs need to be bound prior to deleting them?

Comment: @StevenLu No, it does not need to be bound, but it can be. Quote from the spec page: *If a buffer object that is currently bound is deleted, the binding reverts to 0* (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDeleteBuffers.xhtml)

Answer (score 15):

1: Buffer objects are not "created under" VAOs. Buffer object state is not part of VAO state. VAOs can *reference* buffer objects, but that association is only made by calling `glVertexAttribPointer` (or other *Pointer calls). Simply binding a buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` *does not put it in the VAO*. You can bind buffers to that target without a VAO being bound. This is legal code:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObject);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(someVertices), someVertices, 
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);  //Creates the buffer storage.

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL); //Uses whatever is bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
```

Note that this is not true of `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. That binding is directly part of VAO state. So you need a VAO bound before you can bind to that target.

However, binding to a target is *not creation*. You can bind a buffer to `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER`, create it's storage with glBufferData, and then bind it later for use with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Or as a `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

As to the main thrust of your question, no. The destruction of a VAO will not destroy the buffer objects that it references.

2: There is no standard OpenGL function to detect the amount of available resources. If you attempt to create storage and the implementation is out of resources, you will get a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY​` error.